# using css frame work over own custom css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks, cascade-framework

I'm trying to reach the best css practice on my website using my own custom css till I found out I can use css framework such as bootstrap or foundation zurb instead. I thought using such framework directly without the need of making my own custom css is possible, but it turns out that all css frameworks are limited to some point yet I need to add extra custom css so my site look the way I want.

I want to use css framework because of the fact that it is being served over CDN so no extra bandwidth, and also for load speed and performance.

now my question, is it possible to be using only css framework on a website without the need of adding a custom css?

also how about creating my own custom css and using `@import` to a css framework inside the custom file, is that a good practice?

can anyone enlighten me to an efficient method serving a css file with/without css framework to my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plain framework without writing any custom CSS if you either a) Are happy with how it looks without custom CSS or b) like one of the many themes you can get for such frameworks.

You can `@import` a framework into your own custom CSS - in fact, many frameworks are available as `less` and importing them allows you to use variables from the framework in your own CSS as well.

As far as efficiency goes, are you sure this is the performance problem you have? If you haven't measured the performance, you aren't ready to optimise! It will, of course, be a straight economic trade-off between looking exactly as you want, and keeping the page load fast.

Comment: Thanks @[Steve Fenton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/75525/steve-fenton) for the great answer. now things are very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

using a css framework is always a good option. You can use either bootstrap/foundation. along with the various functionalities on the site it would provide u the animation effects as well. And would help to complete the site faster as they provide the snippets of code. You can use less/sass and have the styling customized in the variables so you wont have to include extra custom css file.